# Embed Skin of .swf file

Tags: apache-flex

I had download a css style like this.

```
Panel
{

closeButtonDisabledSkin: Embed(source="AeonGraphical.swf",symbol="CloseButtonDisabled");
closeButtonDownSkin: Embed(source="AeonGraphical.swf",symbol="CloseButtonDown");
closeButtonOverSkin: Embed(source="AeonGraphical.swf",symbol="CloseButtonOver");
closeButtonUpSkin: Embed(source="AeonGraphical.swf",symbol="CloseButtonUp");
titleBackgroundSkin: Embed(source="AeonGraphical.swf", symbol="PanelTitleBackground");

borderColor: #A1A5AF;
borderAlpha: 1;
backgroundColor: #eeeeee;
backgroundAlpha: 1;
borderThicknessTop: 0;
borderThicknessBottom: 0;
borderThicknessLeft: 4;
borderThicknessRight: 4;
cornerRadius: 10;
headerHeight: 36;
titleStyleName: "mypanelTitle";     

}


.mypanelTitle {
    color: #4b5f0c;
    fontSize: 13;
    fontWeight: bold;
}
```

but I find out the Flex dont have this four part

```
closeButtonDisabledSkin: Embed(source="AeonGraphical.swf",symbol="CloseButtonDisabled");
    closeButtonDownSkin: Embed(source="AeonGraphical.swf",symbol="CloseButtonDown");
    closeButtonOverSkin: Embed(source="AeonGraphical.swf",symbol="CloseButtonOver");
    closeButtonUpSkin: Embed(source="AeonGraphical.swf",symbol="CloseButtonUp");
    titleBackgroundSkin: Embed(source="AeonGraphical.swf", symbol="PanelTitleBackground");
```

How can I use it? and what is this four part means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those "parts" mean that someone created a swf (using flash) with individual skin symbols to use for each of the button states.  You can't use that css without that swf file (or create a new one yourself).